# How to get data from API in metro app

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox, windows-8.1

I am retrieving some values into a combobox from API.

```
class grades
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string grade { get; set; }

    }

    class gradeHelper
    {
        public List<grades> result { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the way I get the data and pass it to the list.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(baseAddress));

            gradeHelper result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<gradeHelper>(content);

            foreach (var item in result.result)
            {                

                cmbGrade.Items.Add(result);                

            }
```

The value that gets filed in my combobox is the path which is the solution name.folder name.class name

> "ted.datamodel.gradehelper"

Comment: cmbGrade.Items.Add(item.grade); Is this you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did the things wrongly, what my view is

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(baseAddress));

gradeHelper data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<gradeHelper>(content);

 foreach (var item in data.result)
 {                

   cmbGrade.Items.Add(item.grade);                

 }
```